# Timeout when connecting RDS from Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am writing a NodeJS application to run as Lambda function and want to connect to RDS without making RDS publicly accessible.

Below are the steps followed:

1. Created a new RDS database and selected create new VPC, subnet and security group.
2. Noted the endpoint, username, password and added it to my NodeJS Mysql connection code.
3. Created a new security group for lambda under the same VPC as of RDS instance.
4. Started a new lambda function and added it under the same VPC created during RDS database creation and added security group created in step 3.
5. In security group of RDS, allowed connection from lambda's security group on port 3306.

Now when i try to run lambda function, i am getting TIMEOUT error.

Please suggest what could be done in this case.

Comment: Can you post your security groups? Also just to double check your Lambda is in private subnets with a NAT?

Comment: What is timing out? The aws api connections to rds, or db clients to db endpoint, e.g. mysql client connecting to a datatabse in rds? Can you post error messages that you get as well?

Comment: Was the database created with `Publicly Accessible = Yes`? Have you been able to connect to the database from anywhere else?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams There's no need for NAT here and, strictly speaking, the Lambda doesn't need to be in a private subnet (though it's better to be there).

Comment: That is correct @jarmod, AWS official documentation does state "Connect your function to private subnets to access private resources.", just trying to get a feel of the setup :)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It is not publicly accessible. I want to keep it like that to keep the DB secure

Comment: @ChrisWilliams You can check these links for screenshots of security group. https://ibb.co/ZM6mt7g https://ibb.co/Q9ThKZQ

Comment: @Marcin Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleConnectTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:409:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:416:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:479:8)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)

{
  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true
}

Comment: A timeout is normally an indication of a security group blocking access, yet your security group configurations _appear_ to be correct. I would recommend temporarily modifying the Inbound rule on the security group associated with the database to **permit all inbound traffic** to see whether that fixes things. Another cause is when the DNS Name of the database incorrectly resolves to a public IP address instead of a private IP address, but since you have `Publicly Accessible = No`, this should not be happening.

Comment: If not tried already, can you try connecting to the RDS / database separately via any SQL client by making the RDS instance as public? If it works, try to connect lambda directly to the RDS instance without VPC / subnet and see if it works.Once these are confirmed to be working, then no issue with RDS. The issue could be localized to access/security group issues.

Comment: I opened the security group for incoming traffic to "Anywhere" on port 3306 but it's still not connecting from a MySQL client